# Refresh div with onclick function?

Tags: php, jquery, html

In my `div`, I show the table having data from the database via PHP protocol, however, when I switch to the other `div` and come back to the the `div` showing the database, I do not see the data anymore, it is just a blank table. So I think i should add reload function in my javascript, is that right? Help me get out of this please

Here is my code

```
<div id="container1">

     <table width="313" border="1">
       <tr>
         <td width="103" height="62"><div align="center">Latitude</div></td>
         <td width="194" class="style5"> <div id="lat" align="center" class="style6">
           <?php 
           const DB_HOST1 = 'localhost';
    const DB_USER1 = 'root';
    const DB_PASS1 = '';
    const DB_NAME1 = 'gmap';
    $mysqli1 = new mysqli(DB_HOST1, DB_USER1,DB_PASS1 ,DB_NAME1);
 if ($mysqli1->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli1->connect_errno} : {$mysqli1->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM gmaptracker1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result1 = $mysqli1->query($query1);
if (!$result1) {
 echo "Invalid query:  {$mysqli1->query($query1)}:{$mysqli1->query($query1)}";
}
           while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){echo  $row1['lat'] . ',N '; ?>
         </div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td height="60"><div align="center">Longtitude</div></td>
         <td> <div align="center" class="style6">
          <?php echo  $row1['lng'] . ',E ';} ?></div></td>
       </tr>

     </table>
</div>
<div id="container2">Container #2<p>Whole bunch of text 2</div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
  function showDiv(idInfo) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('block_left_panel2').getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { sel[i].style.display = 'none'; }
  document.getElementById('container'+idInfo).style.display = 'block';
  return false;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Onclick reload the div only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413200/onclick-reload-the-div-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#your_button_id").click(function(){
  $("#your_div_id").load("url to your php file");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
var sel = document.getElementById('block_left_panel2').getElementsByTagName('div');
```

This piece of code is getting all of your divs, even the ones inside the containers, then hidding then. But you're displaying back just the 2 containers, not its childrens.

A solution for this is to add `class="div-containers"` to your `#container1`and `#container2` divs. In your javascript, change the line above to:

```
var sel = document.getElementsByClassName('div-containers');
```

**The logic is simple**

You hide your main divs (#container1, #container2) using a class and show the one you want (1 or 2) using the id

Comment: and where should i add class="div-containers" in my html code? Anyway, I have moved the contents of containers to new php files and include php files in containers and use the Jquery that Hendry gave me, and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I still get some problem about this, when i add some div into div container, I can't display these div when i switched between div. Can you give me more clear answer about class="div-containers" please?. I'm a newbie.Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add this class to your ``#container1`` and ``#container2`` divs. I'll update my answer.